# How to use "override fun onClick” inside onBindViewHolder in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I want the recycler view to listen to buttons click that exist in other fragments. Where I added the person to the database in the first fragment and the added person should be appeared in the recycler view of the second fragment after I click add.
The same code can work in java but can't in Kotlin. The problem with the override of onClick ("Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'local function'").
Is there a solution to this issue?

The Code is:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position:Int) {
    holder.mRow = mData[position]
    holder.Personname.text = mData[position].name
    holder.Personage.text = mData[position].age.toString()

    holder.mView.setOnClickListener (
        View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick{
                if (null != mListener) {
                    mListener.onFragmentListenr(holder.mRow)
                }
            }
        }
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be simplified to this

```
holder.mView.setOnClickListener {
    mListener?.onFragmentListenr(holder.mRow)
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this makes the recycler view clickable. However, I want it to listen to button clicks from other fragments.

Comment: @LAGS this literally does the same as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Do like this...

```
holder.mView.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                mListener?.onFragmentListenr(holder.mRow)
            }
})
```